# Where to extract the Tomcat package on Ubuntu?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, installation

I always get confused about the meaning of the various directories at the root of Ubuntu.  Where would best practice dictate that the Tomcat package should be placed?  /etc, /var, or another directory?

Comment: Or you could `sudo apt-get install tomcat6` and let Ubuntu handle security updates for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysef, I use the /opt directory for "optional content"

Answer (score 1):

For filesystem organization questions, the best resource is probably the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) .

Packages like Tomcat could reasonably be placed in `/opt` or  `/usr/local/`.